# Optimization of evaluation of polynomials with rational coefficients using algebraic constants

Tags: polynomials

Considering it free to recall constants and already computed values, is there a univariate polynomial with rational coefficients that is easier to evaluate using constants that include irrational algebraic numbers?

I found some polynomials that are just as easy to evaluate in both ways using at least some difficulty measures:

$$\begin{array}{r|l|l}
&x^2 - 2&(x - \sqrt{2})(x + \sqrt{2})\\
\hline
\text{Number of }\times&1&1\\
\text{Number of }\times\,+\,-&2&3\\
\text{Longest serial chain of }\times\,+\,-&2&2\\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{r|l|l}
&x - 1 + x^2&\\
&= (x + 1) x - 1&(x + \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2})(x + \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})\\
\hline
\text{Number of }\times&1&1\\
\text{Number of }\times\,+\,-&3&3\\
\text{Longest serial chain of }\times\,+\,-&2&2\\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{r|l|l}
&3x^2 + 5 x - 4&\\
&= 3x(x + 5/3) - 4&3(x + \frac{\sqrt{73} + 5}{6})(x + \frac{5 - \sqrt{73}}{6})\\
\hline
\text{Number of }\times&2&2\\
\text{Number of }\times\,+\,-&4&4\\
\text{Longest serial chain of }\times\,+\,-&3&3\\
\end{array}$$

but so far none that would be easier to evaluate with radicals, by any of the above listed difficulty measures. The last difficulty measure considers how many cycles the evaluation would take on a computer with infinitely many parallel processing units. I would also be interested in the answer to the analogous question about simultaneous evaluation of a set of multivariate polynomials.

Comment: Maybe $$(x^5+\alpha x^4+\beta x^2+\gamma)(x^5+\alpha' x^4+\beta' x^2+\gamma')$$ where all the Greek letters stand for quadratic irrationals, and the ones with primes are conjugate to the corresponding ones without primes? The product will be degree 10 with all terms present and all coefficients rational.

Comment: How does the second method work in the case of repeated roots? Does it avoid doing several times the same sum?

Comment: For instance, how does it deal with $p(x)=x^4+2x^3-x^2-2x+1=(x^2+x-1)^2$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes you can reuse already computed values for free, so the difficulty by the second measure is 4.

Comment: Another thing: is the "length of a serial $\times$-chain" defined as the maximum number of factors consecutively multiplied between themselves? For instance: "$x^3$ has length $3$" ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli No that would have a length of 2: $x\times x\times x$ is 2 multiplications. Consider that you have a computer that has infinitely many parallel processing units. The length is the number of cycles on that computer to get the final result.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I like the idea but can't get it to work. For example: $(x^5 + (\sqrt{5} - 1)x^4 + (\sqrt{2} - 1)x^2 + \sqrt{3} - 1)(x^5 + (- \sqrt{5} - 1)x^4 + (- \sqrt{2} - 1)x^2 - \sqrt{3} - 1)$ $= x^{10} - 2x^9 - 4x^8 - 2x^7 + (2 - 2\sqrt{10})x^6 - 2x^5 + (1 - 2\sqrt{15})x^4 + (2 - 2\sqrt{6})x^2 - 2$.

Comment: I guess the quadratics all have to be from the same field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well it works if $\alpha = \beta = \gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One distinct possibility is $(x-\sqrt{2})^{2^n}+(x+\sqrt{2})^{2^n}$ for large $n$.  It's easy to see that all the coefficients of this polynomial are integers; more generally, if we define $T_m(x)=(x-\sqrt{2})^m+(x+\sqrt{2})^m$, then by the binomial theorem $\displaystyle T_m(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}2^{i+1}{m\choose 2i}x^{m-2i}$.

Naively, it would seem to take exponential time in $n$ to evaluate $T_{2^n}(x)$ via something like Horner's method, but there's a way of speeding up the integer version: for any fixed $x$ there's a second-degree linear recurrence with constant coefficients for the sequence $T_m(x)$, and so one can use matrix-power methods analogous to those for calculating large Fibonacci numbers to compute $T_{2^n}$ in time linear in $n$.

But the catch here is the constant: those matrix squarings require not less than 3 multiplies each, so computing $T_{2^n}$ with integer arithemtic should require at least $3n+o(n)$ multiplies (and even more additions).  OTOH, it's easy to see that the real-computation version requires only $2n$ multiplies and three additions.

Comment: Great! The result being this it applies also to the multivariate case.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Just keep in mind that this isn't a proof - I don't have a _lower_ bound for the integer evaluation, just a best guess at one!  I suspect there _might_ be a constant-factor bound on the speedup from preconditioning integer polynomials over the reals (vs. preconditioning over the integers or rationals), but I wouldn't be surprised if it were possible to do better; this gets covered in vol. 2 of Knuth, but I haven't looked there in a while.

Comment: Got it. It is an interesting question, perhaps related to polynomial multiplication, which can be sped up using Fourier transform, which also involves irrational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Gerry Myerson's suggestion:

$$(x^5 + \alpha x^4 + \alpha x^2 + \alpha)(x^5 + \alpha'x^4 + \alpha'x^2 + \alpha'),\ \alpha = 1 + \sqrt{2},\ \alpha' = 1 - \sqrt{2}$$
$$= \left(x^5 + (1 + \sqrt{2}) x^4 + (1 + \sqrt{2}) x^2 + (1 + \sqrt{2})\right)\left(x^5 + (1 - \sqrt{2})x^4 + (1 - \sqrt{2})x^2 + (1 - \sqrt{2})\right)\\
= \left(x^5 + (1 + \sqrt{2}) (x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\left(x^5 + (1 - \sqrt{2})(x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\\
= \left(x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5 + \sqrt{2}(x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\left(x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5 - \sqrt{2}(x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\\
= (x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5)^2 - 2(x^4 + x^2 + 1)^2\\
= (x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5)^2 - (x^4 + x^2 + 1)^2 - (x^4 + x^2 + 1)^2\\
= x^{10} + 2x^9 - x^8 + 2x^7 - 2x^6 + 2x^5 - 3x^4 - 2x^2 - 1$$

evaluation without and using irrational algebraic constants:

$$\begin{array}{r|l|l}
&\text{rational}&\text{algebraic}\\
\hline
\text{Number of }\times&5&5\\
\text{Number of }\times\,+\,-&10&10\\
\text{Longest serial chain of }\times\,+\,-&6&6\\
\end{array}$$

Still no luck! Maybe with a more cumbersome $\alpha$ there would be a difference:

$$\left(x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5 + \sqrt{73}(x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\left(x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5 - \sqrt{73}(x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\\
= (x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5)^2 - 73(x^4 + x^2 + 1)^2\\
= (x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5)^2 - \sum^{73}_{i=1}{(x^4 + x^2 + 1)^2}$$

Well that still gives the same counts because multiplication by an integer can be written as a sum. But finally we see a difference in the first difficulty measure with:

$$\left(x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5 + \frac{\sqrt{73}}{2}(x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\left(x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5 - \frac{\sqrt{73}}{2}(x^4 + x^2 + 1)\right)\\
= (x^4 + x^2 + 1 + x^5)^2 - \frac{73}{4}(x^4 + x^2 + 1)^2$$

$$\begin{array}{r|l|l}
&\text{rational}&\text{algebraic}\\
\hline
\text{Number of }\times&6&5\\
\text{Number of }\times\,+\,-&10&10\\
\text{Longest serial chain of }\times\,+\,-&6&6\\
\end{array}$$